# PHP SNMP returns strange hex values in PLAIN and OBJECT mode

Tags: php, snmp

I'm working on php snmp script and I've noticed strange thing. When I set `snmp_set_valueretrieval` to `SNMP_VALUE_PLAIN` or `SNMP_VALUE_OBJECT`, output is some weird characters (sometimes Chinese letters). However, when I set it to `SNMP_VALUE_LIBRARY` everything looks fine. Is there any way to convert these outputs to readable strings? Here is my code

```
snmp_set_quick_print(1);
snmp_set_valueretrieval(SNMP_VALUE_PLAIN);

$example = snmpget(BS_IP, 'public', OID);
echo "Example SNMP_VALUE_PLAIN: " . $example . PHP_EOL;

snmp_set_valueretrieval(SNMP_VALUE_LIBRARY);

$example = snmpget(BS_IP, 'public', OID);
echo "Example SNMP_VALUE_LIBRARY: " . $example . PHP_EOL;

snmp_set_valueretrieval(SNMP_VALUE_OBJECT);

$example = snmpget(BS_IP, 'public', OID);
echo "Example SNMP_VALUE_OBJECT: " . $example->value . PHP_EOL;
```

And here is screenshot of output:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of testing I've noticed that result is binary. So after I've wrapped result with `bin2hex` function result is finally readable.

```
$example = snmpget(BS_IP, 'public', OID);
echo "Example SNMP_VALUE_PLAIN: " . bin2hex($example) . PHP_EOL;
```